# How to navigate to a screen when opening push notification in React Native?

Tags: react-native

**code**

```js
const MypageStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    News,
    Mypage,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Mypage',
  },
);


const postLoginNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Mypage: MypageStack,
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Loading,
  First,
  PostLogin: postLoginNavigator,
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gestureEnabled: false,
  },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    Notifications.addListener(this.subscribeNotification);
  }

  subscribeNotification = (notification) => {
    const { screen = null } = data;
    // screen = 'News'

    if (notification.origin === 'selected') {
      if (screen) {
        dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: screen }));
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

**What I'm trying to do**

When opening notification, I want to navigate to News screen.

But, `dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: screen }));` doesn't work.

I got an error.

> can't find variable: dispatch

I don't know how to navigate. I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dispatch a navigation action you have to use a root navigation object from you props like this =>

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
index: 0,
actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HOME_SCREEN' })]                });

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But I found it more convenient to create a common file called `NavigationService.js` to manage your navigation actions, like this one

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

function getCurrentRoute() {
  let route = _navigator.state.nav
  while (route.routes) {
    route = route.routes[route.index]
  }
  return route
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
  getCurrentRoute
};
```

Update your `<AppContainer/>` to pass the navigation refs to `NavigationSerive` file

```
<AppContainer  ref={ref =>  NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(ref) }
```

And then anywhere in your app just import and call whatever you need

```
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

NavigationService.navigate(routeName, { ...yourParams })
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you. But I got an error. > undefined is not an object (evaluating '_navigator.dispatch') :(

Comment: How do you import the NavigationService ? It should be without brakcets like this one `import NavigationService from './NavigationService';`

Comment: I import as exactly same as you told me :(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you should update your `AppContainer` to set the refs like this `<AppContainer  ref={ref =>  NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(ref) }` I have also updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I still don't know how to give and receive params :(

Comment: Think about params as an object that passes to the new screen, add anything as an object at `...yourParams` section. And also always refer to the documentation of the packages you use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/ you have all the information you need in that docs. Finally dont forget to accept my answer if it is the solution to your problem by click on big gray check button on its left side.

Comment: Thank You So Much!

Comment: best of luck with your project:)